# How to apply a kernel patch for a file in github?

Tags: linux-kernel, patch, page-tables

I wanted to view page table entries. So I build my kernel to 4.1.4 with

```
CONFIG_X86_PTDUMP=y.
```

But still I can not see the page tables entries. Now I understand that the [dump_pagetable.c](https://github.com/rjmccabe3701/LinuxViewPageTables/commit/e2cb0f6810b11a25ff2d5f8aa50ff32dcbb8805e) must be patched. I do not even know where I can find the name of this patch.

1. Can I patch just this file alone? Or do I have to patch a entire dependent folder? If so which folder is it?
2. Also, I am not aware of commands needed to patch a file, please guide me through the process.
3. How to check is patch is successfully done?

Comment: Why just do not read docs about patching Linux kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly looking to the code, I can tell you that you have to split the patch on three (as I can see) logical parts and thus patches. Also you have to follow      kernel coding style: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle. What mentioned in the previous comment is available here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingPatches.